# In DataFrame Pandas how can i filter a timedelta64 by days and chang the value to str?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So currently I’m generating a xlsx from a table that is in MySql with a lot of columns but for this matter I only need one.
I’m using pandas to generate that xlsx, I open the connection to the database and then I do this:

```
import pandas as pd

sql ='Select *from bd.teste'
df=pd.read_sql_query(sql,sql_con_obj.con)
df.to_excel(“generated.xlsx”)
```

If I quickly then do this:

```
df.info()
```

I’m going to have this :

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 147 entries, 0 to 146
Data columns (total 21 columns):
 #   Column               Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------               --------------  -----
 0   Number               147 non-null    object
 1   Date                 147 non-null    object
 ...
 20  IT                   147 non-null    object 
dtypes: object(20)
memory usage: 24.8+ KB
```

The only one that matters is the "Date" column. I then pass the column that is in dtype object to datetime with this:

```
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df.['Date'],dayfirst="True")
```

So now the Date is in datetime and its in this [format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2U8fA.png)

And it shows in the df.info that is in datetime64[ns].
I want to create a new column that is going to deduce my current time with the date and give me the days.

```
df["Difference"]= pds.to_datetime("now") - df['Date']
```

So the table is created and the values on it do match the difference between the dates, the table generated is dtype timedelta64[ns][like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGBWH.png).The big problem comes now. I want to filter the days that are <7 or >7 and be [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UI8xg.png).
Any ideias how to do that ? I though of iterrows but i dont know how to do it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

any kind of conditional setting is very easy. Just use .loc[condition, cols] = value

sampled df:

```
from pandas import DataFrame, to_timedelta
df = DataFrame()
df["deltas"] = [to_timedelta(i, unit= "D") for i in range(1, 11)]
df
   deltas
0  1 days
1  2 days
2  3 days
3  4 days
4  5 days
5  6 days
6  7 days
7  8 days
8  9 days
9 10 days
```

if you do this:

```
cond = df["deltas"] > to_timedelta(7, unit= "D")
```

the condition will look like this:

```
cond
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
6    False
7     True
8     True
9     True
Name: deltas, dtype: bool
```

which you can use in .loc:

```
df.loc[cond, "deltas"] = "> 7"
df.loc[~cond, "deltas"] = "<= 7"

ddf
  deltas
0   <= 7
1   <= 7
2   <= 7
3   <= 7
4   <= 7
5   <= 7
6   <= 7
7    > 7
8    > 7
9    > 7
```

~ this thing converts true to false and vice versa

Comment: when i try to run the first code it says "name 'to_timedelta' is not defined" i then tried to from datetime import timedelta and gives the same error...

Comment: its a pandas function so: from pandas import to_timedelta 
docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html?highlight=to_timedelta#pandas.to_timedelta

Comment: Ok i added pd. before and now shows this error "Length of values (10) does not match length of index (145)" i cant put a range that is fix because the index changes everyday...

Comment: well you can't just copy-paste this into your code, I was using an example df because you seem to know how to create a column of timedeltas... in your question you have shown that you created df["Difference"] which contains the timedeltas. Now make the cond like this: `cond = df["Difference"] > to_timedelta(7, unit= "D")` then use that cond in .loc like this: `df.loc[cond, "Differences"] = "> 7"`

Comment: Yep thats it, my third day searching for the answer and yours did the trick ! Thank you so much!

Comment: One more question, i want to do a cond between 2 days like this ```cond =to_timedelta(7, unit= "D")< df["Difference"] < to_timedelta(25, unit= "D")``` how do i do it ?

Comment: these chains don't work with pandas, you will have to put them in parentheses with an ampersand in between: `cond = (to_timedelta(7, unit= "D") < df["Difference"]) & (df["Difference"] < to_timedelta(25, unit= "D")) `, you should probably read this: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/intro_tutorials/03_subset_data.html#how-do-i-filter-specific-rows-from-a-dataframe   ;)

Comment: Yep, worked again. You the man! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map`.

Example

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'datetime': pd.date_range(
        start=pd.to_datetime('now') - pd.Timedelta(days=10),
        end=pd.to_datetime('now')
    )
})
```

Calculate the difference

```py
df['difference'] = pd.to_datetime('now') - df.datetime
```

Output

```
                     datetime              difference
0  2021-03-15 20:50:30.231135 10 days 00:00:06.153861
1  2021-03-16 20:50:30.231135  9 days 00:00:06.153861
2  2021-03-17 20:50:30.231135  8 days 00:00:06.153861
3  2021-03-18 20:50:30.231135  7 days 00:00:06.153861
4  2021-03-19 20:50:30.231135  6 days 00:00:06.153861
5  2021-03-20 20:50:30.231135  5 days 00:00:06.153861
6  2021-03-21 20:50:30.231135  4 days 00:00:06.153861
7  2021-03-22 20:50:30.231135  3 days 00:00:06.153861
8  2021-03-23 20:50:30.231135  2 days 00:00:06.153861
9  2021-03-24 20:50:30.231135  1 days 00:00:06.153861
10 2021-03-25 20:50:30.231135  0 days 00:00:06.153861
```

then create a boolean column for days that are less than 7

```py
df['less_than_7'] = df.difference.dt.days < 7
```

Output

```
                     datetime              difference  less_than_7
0  2021-03-15 20:50:30.231135 10 days 00:00:06.153861        False
1  2021-03-16 20:50:30.231135  9 days 00:00:06.153861        False
2  2021-03-17 20:50:30.231135  8 days 00:00:06.153861        False
3  2021-03-18 20:50:30.231135  7 days 00:00:06.153861        False
4  2021-03-19 20:50:30.231135  6 days 00:00:06.153861         True
5  2021-03-20 20:50:30.231135  5 days 00:00:06.153861         True
6  2021-03-21 20:50:30.231135  4 days 00:00:06.153861         True
7  2021-03-22 20:50:30.231135  3 days 00:00:06.153861         True
8  2021-03-23 20:50:30.231135  2 days 00:00:06.153861         True
9  2021-03-24 20:50:30.231135  1 days 00:00:06.153861         True
10 2021-03-25 20:50:30.231135  0 days 00:00:06.153861         True
```

finally, map the boolean column to a new column `Difference`

```
map_dict = {False : '>=7', True: '<7'}
df['Difference'] = df.less_than_7.map(map_dict)
df[['datetime', 'Difference']]
```

Output

```
                     datetime Difference
0  2021-03-15 20:50:30.231135        >=7
1  2021-03-16 20:50:30.231135        >=7
2  2021-03-17 20:50:30.231135        >=7
3  2021-03-18 20:50:30.231135        >=7
4  2021-03-19 20:50:30.231135         <7
5  2021-03-20 20:50:30.231135         <7
6  2021-03-21 20:50:30.231135         <7
7  2021-03-22 20:50:30.231135         <7
8  2021-03-23 20:50:30.231135         <7
9  2021-03-24 20:50:30.231135         <7
10 2021-03-25 20:50:30.231135         <7
```

Comment: Let see if i get it, you change the dataframe to only generate 2 columns that dictate the days.The first problem is that i dont know how to then put into the dataframe the other columns that i extrat from mysql, i saw that you could do it manually but the values change everyday and so the rows.